# Getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error trying to setup the Stripe Integration Code

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, exc-bad-access

So my goal is to successfully integrate this API without getting bad access errors. I understand that this error means one of three things, the object is not initialized, the object has already been released, or something else very unlikely.

I really can't figure out where this can possibly be causing an issue, I have Zombies enabled and it doesn't print anything in the console when the app crashes.

**UPDATED ->** In `MyAPIClient.swift` file, I have this method:

```
class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {

var baseURL: String = "https://us-central1-attend-41f12.cloudfunctions.net/createEphemeralKeys"

let ticketVC: TicketFormViewController = TicketFormViewController()

func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {

    ticketVC.getUsersStripeCustomerID { (customerid) in
        if let id = customerid {
            Alamofire.AF.request(self.baseURL, method: .post, parameters: [
                "api_version": apiVersion,
                "customerId": id
            ])
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON { (responseJSON) in
                switch responseJSON.result {
                case .success(let json):
                    completion(json as? [String: Any], nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error creating customer Key (retrieving ephemeral key) with Alamofire. See: MyAPIClient - func createCustomerKey")
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I need this so I can setup the `STPPaymentContext` as well as the `STPCustomerContext`, I do those in the `TicketFormViewController()`:

```
let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient())
var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext


init() {
    self.paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext)
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.paymentContext.delegate = self
    self.paymentContext.hostViewController = self
    self.paymentContext.paymentAmount = 5000
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

I have the delegate methods in the `extension` of the VC, but I don't think those are apart of the issue, the methods are empty anyways. I'm not sure if this is fully correct, I was basically just following along with the [Stripe API Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#set-up-customer-context), but it seems I've done something wrong, if anybody can help me through this that would be great.

**EDIT** Here is an image of the error:

[image: error]

In the console, I also get this:

`warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.`

And lastly, the Zombie message:

`objc[19951]: Class _NSZombie_NSURLRequestInternal is implemented in both ?? (0x17023a250) and ?? (0x169773350). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

This error gets called right when I segue to the vc that contains all the  Stripe `STPPaymentContext` integration code as well as the initialization code. I'm not even sure if my method even does make a request to the Firebase Cloud Function. I segue by pressing a button, I've put breakpoints leading up to the button being pressed and I can't see anything that could be possibly causing the app to crash like this.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to step though the code to see what happens right before the crash? In other words, the last bit of your code that runs before things go awry?

Comment: I've tried everything, I've tried Instruments, analyzing the whole project, can a breakpoint even catch this type of error,  the error points to the `FSTFirestoreComponent.mm` file, and I have no idea what is going on in that file. @jnpdx

Comment: I'm not saying to use a breakpoint to try to catch the crash. I'm saying that you could use the debugger to *step through* your code and see what the last line of *your* code is that gets called before the crash. Set a breakpoint somewhere *before* the crash and then step through until it happens.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it still doesn't work for me. @jnpdx

Comment: "it still doesn't work" -- you mean you can't use the debugger to see what the last line of your code that runs is? Because that's going to be a useful clue to see how to debug this issue.

Comment: 1) Can you provide the full error you're getting? 2) If there is a stack trace, can you add that here too? 3) What point do you get this error? is it when your iOS app makes a request to your Firebase for an EphemeralKey? 4) As the other user said, step through your code as much as you can until you hit the crash, that will atleast help narrow down where the issue lies

Comment: added some more details, @hmunoz